# How to determine email address used to subscribe to Yahoo Group?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I had a Yahoo account subscribed to a Yahoo Group. To this day I occasionally get a junk email as a subscriber to this group. I don't know what username and/or email address I used to create that Yahoo account, so I can't log in and unsubscribe myself from the group. The emails are being sent to "thesundays@yahoogroups.com", not to me directly.

I have a variety of old email addresses that get funneled into my Gmail account.  I've tried all of the email addresses that I can remember using, but I can't log in (or do a "forgot my password") at Yahoo with any of them.

Here's a screenshot of today's email with the email header:

[image: screenshot of email header]

You can see there's no indication of what email address it's being sent to.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Is there any way to contact Yahoo directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check what's appearing in the **X-Apparently-To** header.

[image: full header of email]

On the email message:

1. Click "More"
2. Select "View Full Header"
3. Full header popup will appear

There should be a recognisable email address in the "X-Apparently-To" line which will point to which email address was originally used to sign up for that mailing list or group email.

This also works for when you are sent email via BCC.